# How to get default permalink link text?

Tags: url-rewriting

In WordPress the default permalink URL like this

http://***.com/?p=123

when I change it to this:

http://***.com/new/sample-post/

Is that possible I still can get the default permalink link text, because the second URL is too long, it looks not so good when someone share it.

Answer (score 2):

When you are editing a post you can notice the URL in your browser looks like

```
http://***.com/wp-admin/post.php?post=1351&action=edit
```

The number in the URL corresponds to the ID of your post. So you can access your post with that ID. In this example the short link for the post would be

```
http://***.com/?p=1351
```

When a visitor browsers this URL she will be redirected to the full URL if you have the correct options set in `Settings > Permalinks`.

If you need to get the short URL programatically you can use the [`wp_get_shortlink()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_shortlink) function. This function returns the link, which can then be printed.

Comment: Thanks, Actually, I want display this link at end of each post then the browser can copy this shorter link to share.

Comment: @user18787 I updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can concatenate a url with the [ID](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Post) using [`get_site_url`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_site_url/). This assumes the [ID](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_id/) is valid.

```
<?php 

   echo get_site_url(null, '/?p=' . get_the_ID() );

?>
```

Although [`wp_get_shortlink()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_shortlink) above seems like a better choice.